# what is the correct configuration and dependencies for resteasy-jaxrs and async-http-servlet in JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, jboss-eap-6

I have a web app with REST interfaces running on jboss-eap-6.2.0. All was fine until I implemented an error handler for `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.MethodNotAllowedException`.

At first, `MethodNotAllowedException` could not be resolved to a type. This was fixed by adding a dependency to `resteasy-jaxrs` and a servlet using `HttpServlet30Dispatcher`.

Now, all URLs on the API return `404 Could not find resource for relative`

Here are some dependencies from the web project POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- app was working well (without an implementation of MethodNotAllowedException) before this was added -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7.Final-redhat-2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is the `web.xml` (which was not required at all before the above change)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"> 
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- this module should be loaded automatically via an implicit system dependency in other JBoss modules... but it looks like it isn't -->
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Here is the response received from a POST to http://127.0.0.1:8080/TestApp/rest/invoice

## JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /invoice of full path: http://127.0.0.1:8080/TestApp/rest/invoice/

**JBWEB000309: type** JBWEB000067: Status report

**JBWEB000068: message** Could not find resource for relative : /invoice of full path: http://127.0.0.1:8080/TestApp/rest/invoice/

**JBWEB000069: description** JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.

#### JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1